# Can't create Elixir app with phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have tried to create a web application Elixir with phoenix framework and I am following the official tutorial from github (https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix)

When I am executing the command to create a application I got a error message. I can't understand what I'm missing here. Can you please help me in this?

```
e.g.
  mix phoenix.new photo_blog /home/johndoe/

mr.black :) > mix phoenix.new photo_blog /home/johndoe/
* creating /home/johndoe/photo_blog
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Path.wildcard/2
    (elixir) Path.wildcard("/home/mrblack/projects/eli/phoenix/template/**/*", [match_dot: true])
    lib/mix/tasks/phoenix/new.ex:21: Mix.Tasks.Phoenix.New.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:66: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
    (elixir) src/elixir_lexical.erl:17: :elixir_lexical.run/2
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:296: Code.require_file/2
```

Elixir and Erlang versions that I'm using in my system

```
mr.black :) > iex -v
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 0.14.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Path.wildcard/2 was added to Elixir v0.14.1, so I assume you will need to use v0.14.1 instead of v0.14.0. :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have already fixed. It's working fine. Anyway thank you for your answer.